# Directly editing content on webpage, is it possible?

Tags: admin

Is it possible to edit a website live? I.e simply click on the text you want to change and start typing.

I've found something like this - http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/live-edit/. It's not quite what I want but it's close. So instead of clicking on some kind of admin button to open up a window you would click directly on the webpage to edit the text. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/ Probably its what you looking for.